# Something like Yoneda's lemma

Tags: gn.general-topology, homotopy-theory

This is inspired by [*The Whitehead for maps*](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2672/whitehead-for-maps) question.

Consider two maps `f, g: X\to Y` which happen to induce the same maps (of discrete spaces) `[Z, X] \to [Z, Y]` for every Z. Does this mean `f` and `g` are homotopic?

And what would be the lessons from the answer to this question? I feel like there's something interesting about the way we should ask it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a special case of Yoneda.  Let Z=X and consider the identity map in [X,X]; the hypothesis says that f1=f and g1=g are then equal as elements of [X,Y].

Comment: I didn't see your answer when I was composing mine for some reason :)

Answer (score 1):

I found it myself: the image of `id \in [X, X]` under both maps will be the same class in `[X, Y]`, which is the *definition* of homotopy between `f` and `g`, so the ansewr is yes.