# Chain homotopy: Why du+ud and not du+vd?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

When one wants to prove that a morphism $f_*$ between two chain complexes $\left(C_*\right)$ and $\left(D_*\right)$ is zero in homology, one of the standard approaches is to look for a chain homotopy, i. e., for a map $U_n:C_n\to D_{n+1}$ defined for every $n$ that satisfies $f_n=d_{n+1}U_n+U_{n-1}d_n$ for every $n$. However, this is not strictly necessary: For example, it is often enough to have two maps $U_n:C_n\to D_{n+1}$ and $V_n:C_n\to D_{n+1}$ defined for every $n$ that satisfy $f_n=d_{n+1}U_n+V_{n-1}d_n$ for every $n$. This way, when constructing $U_n$ and $V_n$, one doesn't have to care for them to "fit together", because each is used only one time.

However, at least my experience suggests that one does not gain much from this - when one tries to construct these $U_n$ and $V_n$, they turn out (after some simplification) to be the same.

My question is: What is the deeper reason behind this? Why do chain homotopies like to "fit together" although they don't need to?

I am sorry if this makes no sense...

EDIT: Thanks David, it seems I can't write a single absatz without a stupid mistake.

Comment: Writing f=du+ud shows that f is zero on homology, not that it is an isomorphism. Interesting question, I'll see if I can think of more to say.

Comment: I don't think this is a "soft question", so I'm gonna remove the soft-question tag.

Comment: I think this is related to the fact in topology that a map $f\colon X\to Y$ is a homotopy equivalence iff there are maps $g,h\colon Y\to X$ so that $f\circ g \simeq id_Y$ and $h\circ f \simeq id_X$. In practice you like for $g$ and $h$ to be the same map, but they don't need to be. I haven't worked out the rest of the details as to how exactly this relates to your question about chain complexes, so I might be drawing this comparison in error. I'd be interested to know one way or the other.

Answer (score 24):

**EDITED**, because I think I see the big picture now.

We have the following theorem: let $C$ and $D$ be complexes of projective objects. The following are equivalent: (a) the map $f: C \to D$ is the zero map in the derived category (b) there is a homotopy between $f$ and $0$.

In this theorem, the definition of homotopy is that $f=du+ud$. So my answer to your question is: **In practice, if a map induces the zero map on homology, it is probably zero in the derived category.** There do exist maps which are of the form $du+vd$, but are not of the form $du+ud$, see my other answer.

Paragraph about hereditary algebras deleted because I don't think it was quite right.

---

Some more elementary observations

(1) It is required that $f$ be a map of chain complexes, so $df=fd$. So we want $d(du+vd) =(du+vd)d$ or $dud=dvd$. This doesn't force $u=v$, but it is the easiest way to achieve it.

(2) There is a topological way of thinking of the condition $du+ud=f$, which I learned from Joel Kamnitzer. Let $I$ be the chain complex with $I_1=\mathbb{Z}$, $I_0 = \mathbb{Z}^2$ and the map $I_1 \to I_0$ given by $(1 \ -1)$. Let $\partial I$ be the subchain complex where $(\partial I)\_0=I_0$ and $(\partial I)\_i=0$ for all other $i$.

Then writing $f=du+ud$ is equivalent to finding a map $u:C \times I \to D$ such that, when we restrict to $C \times (\partial I)$, we have the map $f$ on one component and $0$ on the other. $I$ is the chain complex of the obvious triangulation of the unit interval.
Thinking of $I$ as the unit interval, this really is a homotopy between $f$ and $0$. 
I can't think of an analogous geometric motivation for $f=du+vd$.

Comment: Minor comment: You need to assume something like the domain complex being bounded below (or having an exhaustive filtration with subquotients being bounded-below complexes of projectives) in order to be able to show that a map f which is zero in the derived category implies the existence of a homotopy from f to 0.

Comment: @Tyler: complexes are bounded on one side.  @David: The top half of this solution together with the counterexample in the other answer are just a really nice answer.  I learned stuff from it.


Comment: Thanks Greg! For completeness, I'm going to add one more counter-example to the other answer.

Comment: @Greg: It's been my understanding that this isn't convention, it's usually specified if necessary?  There is a perfectly good derived category of unbounded complexes.

Comment: Sorry, I meant WELL-BEHAVED complexes are generally bounded on one side.  I dropped part of what I wanted to say.


Answer (score 17):

Here is an example of a map of chain complexes which can be realized as $du+vd$ but not as $du+ud$.

Let $C$ and $D$ both be the chain complex

$$\cdots 0 \to \mathbb{Z}/p^2 \to \mathbb{Z}/p^2 \to 0 \to \cdots$$

where the nontrivial map is multiplication by $p$.

Map $C$ to $D$ by multiplication by $p$ in the first nontrivial degree, and by zero in the other nontrivial degree. This is $du+vd$, where $u$ is $1$ and $v$ is $0$ (in the only nontrivial degree).

On the other hand, this map cannot be written as $du+ud$. If we had such a representation, then $u$ would be multiplication by $a$ for some $a \in \mathbb{Z}/p^2$. The two vertical maps would then both be $pa$. In particular, it is impossible that one would be zero and the other not.

If we consider these complexes as objects in the derived category of $(\mathbb{Z}/p^2)$-modules, they are complexes of projective objects. So this is an example of a map of complexes which induces zero maps on cohomology but is not zero in the derived category.

What happens if we pass to a quotient category where maps like this are zero? I have no idea! Does anyone?

---

For completeness, I add an example of a map which induces zero on homology and can not be written as $du+vd$. Consider
$$\begin{matrix} 0 & \to & \mathbb{Z} & \to & \mathbb{Z} \\\\
\downarrow &  & \downarrow &  & \downarrow \\\\
\mathbb{Z} & \to & \mathbb{Z} & \to & 0 \end{matrix}$$

where the nontrivial horizontal maps are multiplication by $p$, and the vertical map is the identity. The nontrivial homology is in different degrees in top and bottom, so the map on homology is zero. But any map of the form $du+vd$ would be $0$ modulo $p$ in the central column.

Comment: I think the point is that a true chain homotopy preserves not on homology, but also Bockstein homomorphisms.

Comment: Thanks a lot (particularly for the geometric interpretation of df + fd, which has nothing to do with my question but is a real gem). I'll ponder about your quotient category question a bit more.

Comment: To expand on my previous remark, suppose that a pseudo-homotopy in this sense preserves all Bockstein maps.  Then is it a true chain homotopy?  My guess is, yes, at least if the chain complex is semibounded; and maybe also you need some tameness conditions on the abelian category in which you work.


Comment: In the last sentence, do you mean "0 mod p"?

Comment: Greg, what do you mean by "preserving Bockstein homomorphisms"? At first, are they defined at all? The definition I know involves tensoring an exact sequence of abelian groups with $C_n$ for every $n$, hoping that this will produce another short exact sequence; however, this requires the $C_n$ to be flat.

Comment: On the other hand, the question is interesting even for flat modules. (Not even free modules of rank $1$, i. e. copies of the base ring, can ensure that every map of the form $du+vd$ that commutes with the boundaries has the form $dw+wd$ for some $w$.)

Comment: Still, even when the Bockstein homomorphisms are well-defined, what does "preserving" them mean? Aren't they canonical and therefore always preserved by a map of chain complexes?

Comment: Darij:  You're right that my remark and my thinking were both muddled.  What I should have said is that, in David's examples, your generalized chain homotopies are no longer chain homotopies if you tensor the complexes with $\mathbb{Z}/p$; they create non-zero homology maps in the new coefficients.  My intuition is that their behavior after tensoring can be expressed in terms of the Bockstein maps that become available.  There is a "Bockstein spectral sequence", related to the universal coefficient theorem, that may help clarify the situation.


Comment: "in David's examples": do you mean David's second example? As far as I understand, he made two examples: one of a $du+vd$ map which is not a $dw+wd$ map, and one of a homologically trivial map which is not a $du+vd$ map. The former can only become "better" (i. e., become $dw+wd$) after tensoring with $\mathbb{Z}\slash p$ (and it actually MUST become $dw+wd$, because after tensoring with $\mathbb{Z}\slash p$, every module becomes a vector space, and for vector spaces, $du+vd$ always rewrites as $dw+wd$ - at least, if our complex is bounded from one side).

Comment: So I assume that you are talking about the second example, and the question is whether any map between complexes of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules that is homologically $0$ even after tensoring with any arbitrary $\mathbb{Z}\slash p$ must be a map of the form $du+vd$. Well, this is an interesting question which I'll try to examie. But I fear that I don't really have the prerequisites for this, because I don't even know the definition of a spectral sequence.

Comment: (1) Don't worry what a spectral sequence is.  It is a vast generalization of the Bockstein construction.  It is good enough for you to just study the behavior of Bockstein.  (2) I guess you are right that even the amended remark does not apply to the first example.  Something is there, because both examples do have non-trivial Bockstein maps, but I'm not sure what.


Comment: I am not done thinking over this yet, but let me add that tensoring with $\mathbb{Z}\slash p$ and checking whether it's still homologically zero is not enough. For instance, if we alter David's second example such that the horizontal maps are multiplication by $p^2$ and the vertical map is multiplication by $p$. In this case, our map of chain complexes is homologically $0$ and remains so after tensoring with $\mathbb{Z}\slash p$ and $\mathbb{Z}\slash q$ for any other prime $q$, but it's not $du+vd$. So we should at least try $\mathbb{Z}\slash p^n$, if not even all $\mathbb{Z}\slash m$.

Comment: By the way, nice exercise for linear algebra classes (if someone reading this is holding any): Given a homomorphism between two chain complexes of vector spaces over a field $k$. (Both chain complexes are assumed to be bounded from below.) If this homomorphism is $0$ in homology, then show that it is a chain homotopy (i. e., $dw+wd$ for some $w$). But please check it first; I am not 100% sure about my proof.

Comment: Your exercise is related to the fact that every bounded chain complex over a field is a direct sum of complexes of the form $0 \to k \to 0$ and $0 \to k \to k \to 0$.


Answer (score 9):

Amusingly, I have considered the category of complexes where maps of the form du+vd are killed in: Weight structures vs.  $t$-structures; weight filtrations,  spectral sequences, and complexes (for motives and in general), to appear in J. of K-theory, http://arxiv.org/abs/0704.4003, in section 3.1. My main observation is that the composition of two chain complex morphisms of form du+vd yield a morphism homotopic to zero; so you actually do not forget very much information. In particular, the projection functor from the homotopy category of complexes to this more coarse category is conservative i.e. a non-isomorphism does not become an isomorphism.

You may also find some motivation for introducing such a category in Remark 1.5.2 of my paper.

Comment: That's a very nice result! So if $du+vd$ and $dU+Vd$ are two chain morphisms, then $\left(du+vd\right)\left(dU+Vd\right)=ds+sd$, where $s=vdU+uVd$ (because $dud=dvd$ and $dUd=dVd$ due to $du+vd$ and $dU+Vd$ being chain morphisms). I wish I would understand some of your paper, but I fear I'll have to learn some K-theory first.

Comment: My paper is certainly related to K-theory; yet none of K-theory is necessary to understand it. It could be interesting to you if you understand t-structures.

Answer (score 4):

I have just found another article on this: [Absolute Homology](ftp://ftp.math.mcgill.ca/pub/barr/pdffiles/abshomol.pdf) by Michael Barr.