# Earliest/most standard reference for derived categories of hereditary algebras

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-categories, reference-request

Let $A$ be a hereditary algebra and let $\mathcal{D}$ be the derived category of bounded complex of finitely generated $A$-modules. Then, for any complex $C_{\bullet}$ in $\mathcal{D}$, we have $C_{\bullet} \cong H_{\bullet}(C_{\bullet})$, where the right hand side is the complex whose $i$-th term is $H_i(C_{\bullet})$ and all of whose maps are zero.

I would like to know a standard reference for this. Ideally, I would like to know the original source.

Right now, the only sources I know are lecture notes, such as Section 2.5 of [Keller's notes](http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~keller/ictp2006/lecturenotes/keller.pdf) or Theorem 2.1 in [Lenzing's](http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~keller/ictp2006/lecturenotes/lenzing1.pdf).

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dieter Happel's [book](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=935124) *Triangulated Categories in the representation theory of finite dimensional algebras* is a pretty canonical source, and it includes the result you mention.

(That particular result might be folkloric, though)

Answer (score 2):

In Krause's [*Derived categories, resolutions, and Brown representability*](http://www.math.uic.edu/~bshipley/krause.chicago.pdf), the general version of this result for hereditary abelian categories is proved (Section 1.6).